# ASK : alfresco 5.0.d support api download file

Tags: alfresco

Does alfresco version 5.0.d support the API to download files?

Please help me....

I did not find a reference to that. 
if support, please give me API URL for download files.

Comment: To download one single file that you know the noderef of? To download lots of files in a folder? Something else?

Comment: To download one single file. Please give me URL API if you know.

Comment: Which single file? One you know the `noderef` of? One you know the `path` of? One you know the share view URL of? Other?

Comment: yes i know the noderef, path, and share view URL. I need API for download file.

Comment: Check the Content Get webscript at `/alfresco/s/script/org/alfresco/content/content.get` - that has a few URL forms which take a noderef, should be what you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script for downloading content.

Example URL:

`https://localhost:8080/alfresco/s/api/node/content/workspace/SpacesStore/eb2aad95-0acf-43df-bc47-2838e6cdbded?a=true`

Pls check this webscript for additional parameters:

```
https://localhost:8080/alfresco/s/script/org/alfresco/content/content.get
```